# How to send data from two external php scripts

Tags: php, http, curl, post, https

I have a form at example.com/login.html. It will send POST data to secondexample.com/login.php. It has to be cross-domain because secondexample.com's PHP script will have access to that domain's file system. It will check some files and send the information to example.com/main.php. The problem is that I don't know how to send the data. I am not able to use GET info because the information is too large. I do not want to use any client-side methods such as JavaScript or HTML. secondexample.com/login.php needs to redirect directly to example.com/main.php through something like `header("LOCATION: example.com/main.php")`.

Comment: You probably need to provide alot more context. This sounds something of a spamming or hacking attempt. If both sites are yours, then you obviously use different methods. Like API / curl or root path inside the same server. But files in login sounds weird.
So to answer your question: You need correct approach. GET and POST are not it.

Answer (score -1):

you can `$_POST` inputs `secondexample.com/login.php` then return token to session start

```
<?php
$user= $_POST['user'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

//check user and pass in db correct
if($pass==$dbpass){
$key= 12345678; //this key used like password

$encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $myVarIWantToEncodeAndDecode, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
header("LOCATION: example.com/main.php?encoded=".$encoded) 
exit;
}
```

Then crate session in `example.com/main.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$key= 12345678; //this key used like password
$encoded=$_POST['encoded'];
$decoded = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encoded), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0")
if($decoded==$key){
$_SESSION['status']= $status;  
}else{
header("LOCATION: example.com/logout.php") 
exit;
}
// your page message here
```

I think it help you